# How to select multiple fields (LINQ)

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

How to change the following linq query to select another field value `Field<int>("data_entry")`,i want to select multiple fields .

---

```
 var a = DF_Utilities.GetAvailableTasks(empnum, 1).AsEnumerable().Where(
    p => p.Field<int>("task_code") == int.Parse(drpTasks.SelectedValue)).Select(p => p.Field<int>("cand_num")).First();
```

---

```
p.Field<int>("cand_num"),Field<int>("data_entry")
```

instead of `p.Field<int>("cand_num")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

```
var a = DF_Utilities.
    GetAvailableTasks(empnum, 1).
    AsEnumerable().
    Where(p => p.Field<int>("task_code") == int.Parse(drpTasks.SelectedValue)).
    Select(p => new 
    {
        candNum = p.Field<int>("cand_num"),
        dataEntry = p.Field<int>("data_entry")
    }).
    First();
```

Comment: I want the first() , cuz i get one row